# display more that one category from mysql

Tags: php, database

When I put an item in the database I can chose different "Used" categories .

For example I have Used, Barely Used, Rough. I am wanting all them to display on the same page.

Right now I have this code

```
$SQL_GetEquipment = "SELECT * FROM `new_equip` WHERE `condition`='Used' $SQLCat $Limit";
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: your question is unclear please explain more

Comment: you need to add some more condition in select query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...where (`condition`='Used' OR `condition`='Barely Used' OR `condition`='Rough')...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
$SQL_GetEquipment = "SELECT * FROM `new_equip` WHERE `condition` LIKE '%Used' OR `condition` LIKE '%Barely Used%' OR `condition` LIKE '%Rough%' $SQLCat $Limit";
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/entering-queries.html) you simply use OR condition it will help you

```
$SQL_GetEquipment = "SELECT * FROM new_equip WHERE condition='Used' or condition='Barely Used' OR condition='Rough'  $SQLCat $Limit";
```